# P-value vs. Bayesian statistics

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, p-value

Are there any theoretical considerations between $p$-value and the Bayesian statistics? I mean say, any theorem regarding **both** of these two concepts at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Lindley's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindley%27s_paradox) is helpful for you. This is about the discrepancy between Frequentist significance and Bayesian posterior probability.